# Getting jquery to check if userid is valid before submitting form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a form that I want to check if the userID is already used and then display the answer to the user before submitting the form. I found a way to do it through another site, but the code comes back with e.nodename is undefined. I am using jQuery 1.6. Any thoughts on how to do this? I am very new to jQuery. Thanks.

Comment: what do you mean *through another site*?

Answer (score 1):

I would do a

```
$.getJSON("http://host.com/?action=isUserIDavailable&userid=" + userid, function(){});
```

to check if the userid is available before you submit the form

Answer (score 0):

lets assume that your submit button is something like this

```
<input type="submit" id="submit-button" name="submit" value="submit"/>
```

you need to send an ajax request to the server with the userID i guess your userID is something like a select menu

```
<select id="user-id" name="user-id">
   <option value="1">xx</option>
   ....etc
</select>
```

your javascript code will be something like that

```
$(function(){
 $('#submit-button').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault(); // to prevent posting the form
  //now sending ajax call to the server to check if the userID is valid
  $.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: {'userID':$('#user-id').val()}
    success: function(data) {
      if(data == "OK"){
        //the id is value
        //you can post the form by using $('#form-id').submit();
      }else{
        //the id is n't valid
      }
    }
  });

 });
});
```